# Case when SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, case

I have a single table with no relations.  When the field countyName is a zero length string I need `Statewide` to be in the result set.  Otherwise, I need then value of the field to stay as it is, e.g.: [image] notice how in the second column there is 'Statewide' and 'countyName'.  countyName should be the original value actually stored in the database.

```
`countyName`  `address`
               blah blah
Jackson        blah blah
```

needs to be (first rows on both examples are column names)

```
countyName     address
Statewide      blah blah
Jackson        blah blah
```

Here's what I tried, you can ignore the rest of the fields in this example

```
select case servicetype
       when 'cr' then 'Community Resource'
       when 'ed' then 'Education'
       when 'fb' then 'Faith-based'
       when 'me' then 'Medical Equipment'
       when 'hc' then 'Health Care'
       else 'Other' 
       end as serviceType

       ,case countyName
       when '' then 'Statewide'
       else 'countyname' end

       ,name
       ,physicaladdress
       ,city
       ,statelocation
       ,zip
       ,phone
       ,website
       from main

      order by countyName, servicetype, name
```

Comment: What's the problem with your query? Do you got any error? unexpected results??

Comment: the query runs, but with the second case statement, the else doesn't return the original value of what was in the row, everything is 'countyName'

Comment: @MahmoudGamal screen cap was edited in.

Comment: Then you don't have a value of `''` in that field, you have a value of `NULL` in that field.  Try one of the following...  `COALESCE(countyName, 'Statewide')` or `CASE WHEN countyName IS NULL OR countyName = '' THEN 'Statewide' ELSE countyName END`.

Comment: Have you checked whether the countyName is blank or is null ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Despite not saying exactly what results you're expect, my **guess** would be that you don't want to return the literal of 'countyname'.  What you want is the value in the column.

So try replace the current case statement with...

```
,case countyName
when '' then 'Statewide'
else countyName end
```

As an extra safety net, you can also check for `NULL` values using `ISNULL`...

```
,case ISNULL(countyName,'')
when '' then 'Statewide'
else countyName end
```

Comment: Not a problem @woot, glad to have helped.  Good luck with the rest of your project

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
case when isnull(countyName,'') = '' then 'Statewide' else countyname end
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for the "IFNULL" function.

simply use it this way: `SELECT ...,ISNULL( column, "fallback value" ),...` in your case

Comment: supid me, marc_s is right. Getting old and confused by all the sql-derivates.

Answer (score 0):

Try this... IsNULL should be checked.

`case ISNULL(countyName,'')
       when '' then 'Statewide'
       else 'countyname' end`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT   ProductNumber, Category =
      CASE ProductLine
         WHEN 'R' THEN 'Road'
         WHEN 'M' THEN 'Mountain'
         WHEN 'T' THEN 'Touring'
         WHEN 'S' THEN 'Other sale items'
         ELSE 'Not for sale'
      END,
   Name
FROM Production.Product
ORDER BY ProductNumber;
```

GO